# Angular: ng-model defined only when select is dirty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The issue I'm having is that I'd like to have a text input be blank while it has a defined ng-model that has a default value, then, when the input becomes dirty, I'd like that specific ng-model to be redefined. Example:

```
<span ng-init="level='Base'">{{level}}</span>
<input ng-model="level" placeholder="Specify Level">
```

Optimally, the example above would say "Base" as a default value in the span, but not in the input (so the placeholder is visible) until the input becomes dirty with the redefined 'level' value. I've tried something along these lines, but was unable to achieve what I was looking for:

```
<span ng-init="level='Base'">{{level}}</span>
<input ng-model="noop" ng-change="checkDirty()" name="lvl" id="lvl" placeholder="Specify Level">

// Controller code
$scope.checkDirty = function(){
  if ($scope.myform.lvl.$dirty) {
    angular.element("#lvl").attr("ng-model", "level")
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't see a real scenario when that would be needed, can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: I don't think that's entirely relevant, but yes there's a use case. Like I said, I'd like to display the initial value in a span while the input still maintains its placeholder. Then when the input changes, the span should too.

Comment: what you are describing doesn't make much sense, so yes the use case would be very relevant.  You are asking how to set a variable to blank and a value at the exact same time, which isn't really logical.

Comment: does the span *have* to be set to the same variable? could it be set to a different variable, with a function that uses `$watch` on the value of the textbox?

Comment: There is no need for a change event, you can directly do this `<span>{{level ? level : 'Base'}}</span>` [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UNPSP5ANFZpOYbTlGeAK?p=preview)

Comment: @anpsmn Thank you. That's all I was looking for. Just a way to display a default val and then change it with ng-change. I'll accept your comment as an answer!

Comment: @user3181113 I was just adding that as an answer before your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a change event to check if the form is dirty. You can directly have a condition inside the span element.

```
{{level ? level : 'Base'}}
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <span>{{level ? level : 'Base'}}</span>
    <input ng-model="level"  name="lvl" id="lvl" placeholder="Enter level">

  </body>
```